# How to Reference A DataTable From Application to DLL

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dll, datatable, replication

### Goal

I have a main application that generates numbers for the company. I will be using this number generation in my main application and in an AutoCAD plugin. That being said, I created a class library (DLL) that will be utilized in both places. This prevents me from making modifications in both places if ever I need to. I just open the DLL, make the changes and rebuild.

The information is stored in DataTables and I want to use my main applications' DataTables as a reference in my DLL class library.

### Current Situation

When I edit an item from my main application, I use the DLL to prompt the edit window (this is what is used in my application and my AutoCAD plugin). Once the user is done, they save the changes. The only issue is, the DataTables in my main application are not modified, only those in the DLL. Therefore I do not see the changes replicated.

From my main application, I call the Dll.Initializer.InitializeDataTables() to load the information in my DataTables. This is the same code I utilize in my main application load as well, I know this isn't the way to go. This is why I'm looking to some sort of reference between the DataTables.

```
Public Class Initializer
    Public Shared Sub InitializeDataTables()
        'The following Loads information in the DataTables
        clsPlatform.LoadPlatform()
        clsState.LoadStates()
        clsEmploye.LoadEmploye()
        clsClient.LoadClient()
        clsArticle.LoadArticle()
        clsLayout.LoadLayout()
        clsCountry.LoadCountries()
        clsOffice.LoadOffices()
        clsProgramVariable.FillAppEngs()

        myApplicationEngineers = clsProgramVariable.GetAppEngs()
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can I reference the DataTables so when a change is done in the DLL, I can see it replicate in my main application?

Comment: Do you pass the datatables from your main application to your DLL via parameter? Are they accesible via properties? Do the method you call from your DLL returns them? I think we´re gonna need something more in order to help... some `code` perhaps...

Comment: @JoshPart At the moment I just call the loaders. I tried passing my main application DataTables via parameter but my DLL DataTables were read only for some reason?